I have Radiomaster Boxer CC2500. Can i add an external elrs module on my Tx to make it elrs compatible or do i need to buy a new Tx?
I bought a CC2500 version of Tx which is sightly outdated. I didn't know this while buying. I came to know that i can use FrSky rx to make my drone compatible with my tx. If i want to make my tx ELRS version, can i use an external bay RadioMaster Bandit Micro 915MHz ExpressLRS RF Module? Or do i need to buy a new tx?

The CC2500 version of the Boxer is not outdated at all! It's in fact the same as the 4-in-1 and ELRS version, but only differs in the internal RF (remote frequency) module that is used.
You have multiple ways of converting your current RadioMaster Boxer to one that can work with the ExpressLRS ecosystem.

Keep your internal CC2500 RF module, and buy an external  like the RadioMaster Ranger Micro or RadioMaster Ranger.  Both will give you exactly the same options, but the full size RadioMaster Ranger features a fancy screen and some better cooling, making it possible to do a hack that let the unit output 2 Watts. Please note though that even low outputs like 100mW will give you plenty of range already!

The benefits is that it's plug and play and you don't need to open up your radio. Just plug it in and in your model menu pick ' CRSF ' as external module. You're good to go after that!
The other benefit is that you can keep using your internal CC2500 module, enabling you to also use RF protocols like FrSky, Futaba, etc.

Remove your current internal CC2500 RF module and buy a internal ELRS RF module for the boxer. They are available here and there - in Europe you can check out the official RadioMaster service center TekRC EU - and are easy to install, but it requires opening your transmitter, unplugging a connector and reseating the new module. The benefit is that you don't require taking an external expresslrs module with you, the drawback is that you lose the CC2500 protocols like FrSky, Futaba, etc.


Thank you for your answer. There is not much on this topic elsewhere and your answer is very helpful. I am having the same problem and considering replacing the internal CC2500 module with an ELRS module. Do we have to update the firmware of the transmitter to tell it that now it is connected to ELRS and not CC2500?
